# django get_queryset get() returns more than one object error

Tags: django

For these models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()


class Failure1(models.Model):
    FAILURE_CHOICES = (
    ('SC', 'Screen'),
    ('BA', 'Battery'),
    ('BX', 'Box'),
    # etc, with 10+ choices
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=FAILURE_CHOICES)

class Failure2(models.Model):
    FAILURE_CHOICES = (
    ('SZ', 'Blah'),
    ('BB', 'Basdasd'),
    ('BD', 'etc'),
    # etc, with 10+ choices
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=FAILURE_CHOICES)


class Market(models.Model):
    MARKET_CHOICES = (
    ('ED', 'Education'),
    ('CO', 'Commercial'),
    # etc, with 10 choices
    )

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    market = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=MARKET_CHOICES)
    failure1 = models.ManyToManyField(Failure1, blank=True)
    failure2 = models.ManyToManyField(Failure2, blank=True)   


class Failure_MarketManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(Failure_MarketManager, self).get_queryset().filter(Q(failure2__name__isnull=False) | Q(failure1__name__isnull=False))

class Failure_Market(Market):
    class Meta:
    proxy = True

    objects = Failure_MarketManager()
```

What I'm after is an admin changelist that shows only those Markets with any Failures (from either the Failure1 or Failure2 list).

With the proxy model above, if there is more than one Failure, I get a 'get() returns more than one object' error.

If I change it to `get_queryset().exclude(Q(failure2__name__isnull=True) | Q(failure1__name__isnull=True))` I get zero results - why is this ?

If I change it to `get_queryset().filter(~Q(failure2__name__isnull=False) | ~Q(failure1__name__isnull=False))` it works - why does this work but the filter Q doesn't ?

Comment: That is valid error for `.get()`, it should only return 1 object otherwise you will get multiple object exception. Caller of `.get()` should handle this. If your really want, you can change your `get_queryset()` to return only 1 object by slicing.

Comment: What is the caller of .get() in this scenario, when i'm using get_queryset() in the admin ?